# checkbox autopostback without refreshing page asp net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have this checkbox  that I need to be `AutoPostBack="True"` so that I can trigger `OnCheckedChanged="chkCompany_OnCheckedChanged"`. The problem is that I dont want the page to be refreshed and redirected, I want the user to stay put exactly where they are.

ASPX:

```
<asp:CheckBox OnCheckedChanged="chkCompany_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="chkCompany" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="chkCompany" runat="server" />
```

C#:

```
protected void chkCompany_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkCompany.Checked)
        {
            txtName.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            txtName.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must use UpdatePanel control, and put your code within UpdatePanel control

Comment: I tried that, it did not work. Unless you create a post and show me exactly how?

Comment: If all you are doing is changing the visibility of another element when the checkbox is checked I would recommend using JavaScript

Comment: That's not all I am doing, I need to implement more code later on, I already have a solution with jQuery, but I cant use that!

Comment: If you use c# code and AutoPostback=true then surely it will postback on page... either you have to use javascript

Comment: I cannot use JavaScript since I need the value of the checkbox to determine other values in C# and SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use UpdatePanel control to do this

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox OnCheckedChanged="chkCompany_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="chkCompany" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="chkCompany" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Keep your code inside update pannel.

Comment: It says: 'Element 'CheckBox' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.'

Comment: Its just a warning message not an Error . You can skip warnings.

Comment: No it's not, my whole application freezes to white when trying to debug.

Comment: Sorry I missed <ContentTemplate> tag. Updated the answer.

Comment: I have Included script manager in my answer .
The ScriptManager control manages client script for AJAX-enabled ASP.NET Web pages. By default, the ScriptManager control registers the script for the Microsoft Ajax Library with the page. This enables client script to use the type system extensions and to support features such as partial-page rendering and Web-service calls.
More Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript to do this,if Update panel does not work.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <script type=text/javascript>
        function CheckedChanged()
    {
       if((document.getElementById('chkCompany').checked))
`{`


      document.getElementById('txtname').Visible=false;
    }

`else`   

    {

     document.getElementById('txtname').Visible=false;

`}`

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


     <asp:CheckBox OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="chkCompany" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="chkCompany" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"/>

</body>
</html>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution but for `DropDownCheckList`.
The same works for `CheckBox`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cwc:DropDownCheckList runat="server" ID="myId" AutoPostBack="True" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myId" /> 
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```